# Understanding the gdb backtrace full report

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11, segmentation-fault, gdb

Can somebody please help me in understanding the issue that caused this segmentation fault.
This points to a place where I access an Iter to a map.

The relevant code where it points is:

```
cout << "Iterate the Map:" << endl;     
    for(Iter=activevalues->begin(); Iter != activevalues->end(); ++Iter)
        {
            Allactivevalues.push_back(Iter->first); [Here on this line (/Address/to/file/file.cpp:784)]
        }
```

The gdb log report is:

```
(gdb) bt full

#0  0x00000000004401ac in Class::Funtion (this=0x1d16ec90) at /Address/to/file/file.cpp:784
    StdVectorVariable = {<std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<int>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, 
      _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}

#1  0x0000000000432633 in Class1::Function1 (this=0xdc8035d0, ssMsg=0x2aaaac8acf90 "\003") at /Address/to/file1/file1.cpp:570
    bytSend = 164
    log = {<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >> = {<std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >> = {<std::ios_base> = {_vptr.ios_base = 0x2ae764454b80, static boolalpha = <optimized out>, 
        static dec = <optimized out>, static fixed = <optimized out>, static hex = 858927408, static internal = 0, static left = <optimized out>, static oct = <optimized out>, static right = <optimized out>, 
        static scientific = <optimized out>, static showbase = <optimized out>, static showpoint = <optimized out>, static showpos = <optimized out>, static skipws = <optimized out>, 
        static unitbuf = <optimized out>, static uppercase = <optimized out>, static adjustfield = <optimized out>, static basefield = <optimized out>, static floatfield = <optimized out>, 
        static badbit = <optimized out>, static eofbit = <optimized out>, static failbit = <optimized out>, static goodbit = <optimized out>, static app = <optimized out>, static ate = <optimized out>, 
        static binary = <optimized out>, static in = <optimized out>, static out = <optimized out>, static trunc = 1141968882, static beg = <optimized out>, static cur = <optimized out>, 
        static end = <optimized out>, _M_precision = 6, _M_width = 0, _M_flags = 4098, _M_exception = std::_S_goodbit, _M_streambuf_state = std::_S_goodbit, _M_callbacks = 0x0, _M_word_zero = {_M_pword = 0x0, 
          _M_iword = 0}, _M_local_word = {{_M_pword = 0x0, _M_iword = 0}, {_M_pword = 0x0, _M_iword = 0}, {_M_pword = 0x0, _M_iword = 0}, {_M_pword = 0x0, _M_iword = 0}, {_M_pword = 0x0, _M_iword = 0}, {
            _M_pword = 0x0, _M_iword = 0}, {_M_pword = 0x0, _M_iword = 0}, {_M_pword = 0x0, _M_iword = 0}}, _M_word_size = 8, _M_word = 0x2aaaac8ace58, _M_ios_locale = {static none = -1, 
          static ctype = <optimized out>, static numeric = <optimized out>, static collate = <optimized out>, static time = 149717832, static monetary = <optimized out>, static messages = <optimized out>, 
          static all = <optimized out>, _M_impl = 0x2ae76446ab80, static _S_classic = <optimized out>, static _S_global = <optimized out>, static _S_categories = <optimized out>, static _S_once = <optimized out>}}, 
      _M_tie = 0x0, _M_fill = 32 ' ', _M_fill_init = true, _M_streambuf = 0x2aaaac8acd28, _M_ctype = 0x2ae76446ae00, _M_num_put = 0x2ae76446b120, _M_num_get = 0x2ae76446b110}, _vptr.basic_ostream = 0x2ae764454b58}, 
  _M_filebuf = {<std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >> = {_vptr.basic_streambuf = 0x2ae764454970, 
      _M_in_beg = 0x2aaab00009a0 "Output:Id:31,PID:37,InId:65928,bysll:2,EhId:1100000005231634\n", 
      _M_in_cur = 0x2aaab00009a0 "Output:Id:31,PID:37,InId:65928,bysll:2,EhId:1100000005231634\n", 
      _M_in_end = 0x2aaab00009a0 "Output:Id:31,PID:37,InId:65928,bysll:2,EhId:1100000005231634\n", 
      _M_out_beg = 0x2aaab00009a0 "Output:Id:31,PID:37,InId:65928,bysll:2,EhId:1100000005231634\n", 
      _M_out_cur = 0x2aaab00009a0 "Output:Id:31,PID:37,InId:65928,bysll:2,EhId:1100000005231634\n", _M_out_end = 0x2aaab000299f "", _M_buf_locale = {static none = -1, 
        static ctype = <optimized out>, static numeric = <optimized out>, static collate = <optimized out>, static time = 149717832, static monetary = <optimized out>, static messages = <optimized out>, 
        static all = <optimized out>, _M_impl = 0x2ae76446ab80, static _S_classic = <optimized out>, static _S_global = <optimized out>, static _S_categories = <optimized out>, static _S_once = <optimized out>}}, 
    _M_lock = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __nusers = 0, __kind = 0, __spins = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, __next = 0x0}}, __size = '\0' <repeats 39 times>, __align = 0}, _M_file = {
      _M_cfile = 0x2aaab0003d00, _M_cfile_created = true}, _M_mode = 17, _M_state_beg = {__count = 0, __value = {__wch = 0, __wchb = "\000\000\000"}}, _M_state_cur = {__count = 0, __value = {__wch = 0, 
        __wchb = "\000\000\000"}}, _M_state_last = {__count = 0, __value = {__wch = 0, __wchb = "\000\000\000"}}, 
    _M_buf = 0x2aaab00009a0 "Output:Id:31,PID:37,InId:65928,bysll:2,EhId:1100000005231634\n", _M_buf_size = 8192, _M_buf_allocated = true, _M_reading = false, _M_writing = true, _M_pback = 0 '\0', 
    _M_pback_cur_save = 0x0, _M_pback_end_save = 0x0, _M_pback_init = false, _M_codecvt = 0x2ae76446b040, _M_ext_buf = 0x0, _M_ext_buf_size = 0, _M_ext_next = 0x0, _M_ext_end = 0x0}}

#2  0x000000000042a7b2 in Class2::ThreadFunction2 (this=0xdc802520) at /Address/to/Nfile/Nfile.cpp:280
    Msg = (unsigned char *) 0x2aaaac8acf90 "\003"
    one_queue_buffer = {msg = "\003\000\002\000\037\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\037\000\000\000\"\000\000\000%\000\000\000\210\001\001\000\000\000\002\000C�\f\000\031", '\0' <repeats 12 times>}
    stomType = (short unsigned int *) 0x2aaaac8acf90
    Id1 = (short unsigned int *) 0x2aaaac8acf92
    Id = (unsigned int *) 0x2aaaac8acf94

#3  0x000000000042d139 in Class::run1 (this=0xdc802520) at /Address/to/Nfile/Nfile.hpp:152
No locals.

#4  0x00000000004295c3 in boost::_mfi::mf0<void, ThreadBase>::operator() (this=0xdc80a408, t=@0xdc802520) at /home/dev4/boost_1_54_0/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:70
No locals.

#5  0x00000000004294d4 in boost::_bi::list1<boost::reference_wrapper<ThreadBase> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, ThreadBase>, boost::_bi::list0> (this=0xdc80a418, f=@0xdc80a408, a=@0x2aaaac8ad0be)
    at /home/dev4/boost_1_54_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp:253
No locals.

#6  0x000000000042937b in boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, ThreadBase>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::reference_wrapper<ThreadBase> > >::operator() (this=0xdc80a408)
    at /home/dev4/boost_1_54_0/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20
    a = {<No data fields>}

#7  0x000000000042924a in boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, ThreadBase>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::reference_wrapper<ThreadBase> > > >::run (this=0xdc80a250)
    at /home/dev4/boost_1_54_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:117
No locals.

#8  0x00002ae763b4e0d2 in thread_proxy () from /home/dev4/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
No symbol table info available.

#9  0x0000003b970064a7 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.

#10 0x0000003b964d3c2d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

My program is multi-threaded program; Can the issue be that some other thread is accessing the same Iter->first at the same time while its been accessed by the pointed code. Can it be clearly understood from the gdb log ?

Additional Details:
The Iter gets accessed at the same place previously a number of times, The code runs fine for 5-6 minutes and prints correct output then segmentation fault occur.

In the #0 th stack place, doesn't it says that the fields are basically ;NO data field; and ;No Data field;.

The activeValues is basically a std::map ; int are IDs.
Could it be possible that some other place which is there in the gdb report is accessing the Iter->first at the same time as the "(/Address/to/file/file.cpp:784" line is accessing.
The code is huge: the possible ways I can think of maybe are that the when the program enters inside the loop the activevalues gets changed by some other part of the code, basically code keeps updating the actievalues, but once the Iter enters the for loop by iterating over activevalues shouldn't it just have its value whatever is there ?

Comment: Show us more code. I see no information where is Allactivevalues comes from. Perhaps you using reference to local std::vector which is out of scope in other thread.

Comment: I have referenced the std::vector quite a number of times before as well, it worked fine; I mean it printed lots of output; the code ran for 5 minutes perfectly then it occurred. Added some details in the question, if they could be helpful.

Comment: What's work fine? Thread 1 gave reference to local vector to Thread 2.  While Thread 1 is alive and local vector still alive it should be fine. But if Thread 1 is exits, vector goes out of scope and Thread 2 will try to access destructed object over that reference? Maybe it's your case?